# RestSharp - Error - Could not load file or assembly -The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, api, rest, version, restsharp

I added the RestSharp nuget package to my VS2019 Test Project (MSTest)

The below error is thrown while executing the test.

```
Message: 
    Test method RestSharp.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

.Net framework 4.8,
RestSharp = 106.11.4

What could be the issue ?

Below are the packages added to the solution

[image]

Comment: Are there any references to version 106.0.0.0 in your .config file? Also, is your solution a single project, or multiple projects? If multiple, then each project would need to target the same version.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, No there are no references. Below are the only references I had. I also have just one project in the solution. In fact I created this new solution just to isolate the issue I had in another project where I ran into some issues related to RestSharp. <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="106.11.4" targetFramework="net48" />

Answer (score 1):

I got the following error message when my .NET Core 3.1 application was deployed on Windows 7 IIS, and RestSharp DLL was also copied in root deployment folder:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After some workaround I found out that I forgot to copy appname.deps.json file to deployment folder.

P.S: Although this is late reply but maybe my solution is helpful for someone else on this platform

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you added the nuget package only to your main project but not to your test project. If this is not the case, please check all your `app.config` and `web.config` files in the solution and see if there is a `<dependentAssembly>` entry for RestSharp anywhere. If there is, try removing it. Of course do it after you're sure all your projects referenced the same version of RestSharp nuget package. And also make sure they didn't directly reference the DLL file from different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Apply manually like "Add Reference" in your TEst project and browse in your drive. Mostly you will get this assembly in Package folder.